# Add text field value to this function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a working script that when loaded (as part of a Chrome extension) on a page it modifies the onclick events to include a setInterval value with a little random math. What I'd like to do is have a text field on the page that allows me to input a value in ms rather than hard coding it in the js file. Nothing I've tried so far has worked. I've included a beginning version that adds a text field but, I can't get it to use the value I type in the text field in the function in place of the 240000 that's there now.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```js
    $(function() {
      var automiss = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];
      automiss.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input style="margin-bottom:4px;" type="text" name="newbutval" id="newbutval"/>');

      if (document.URL.indexOf("missions.game") > 0) {
        $('.btn.startBtn.btn-large').each(function() {
          var current = $(this).attr("onclick");
          $(this).attr("onclick", "setInterval(function(){if (Math.random() > 0.3) {" + current + "}}, 240000);");
        });
      }
    });


//Below is the working script - THANK YOU!
$(function()
{
  if (document.URL.indexOf("missions.game") > 0){
    var automiss = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];
    automiss.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<input style="margin-bottom:4px;" type="text" name="newbutval" id="newbutval"/>');
    $('#newbutval').on('change',function(){

    $('.btn.startBtn').each(function(){
    var current = $(this).attr("onclick");
    var newvalue = parseInt($("#newbutval").val());
    $(this).attr("onclick", "setInterval(function(){if (Math.random() > 0.3) {" + current + "}}," + newvalue + " );");
    });

    })
  }
});
```

Comment: What about `parseInt($("#newbutval").val())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$("#newbutval").val()` to get the input's value, but as the input's type is `text`, you would probably want to parse the value as an int as well:

```
parseInt($("#newbutval").val())
```

Comment: So would I just create a new var to hold the value and then use it at the end of the function?
`var newvalue = parseInt($("#newbutval").val())`

Comment: and then the new function would be
`$(this).attr("onclick", "setInterval(function(){if (Math.random() > 0.3) {" + current + "}}, newvalue );");`

Comment: @ShcFinalJudgement Yes, exactly.